# PHP script returning "undefined" on submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm building a small app, which is basicly a form built in HTML and jQuery mobile, I've deployed it to the web, and to my iOS-version of the app, and it works like a charm. But now when trying to deploy on the android-version of the app, I just get "undefined" on the screen when submiting, no "undefined variable" or anything else, just "undefined".

Do anyone have some form of solution to this problem? I'm using PhoneGap to deploy HTML/CSS/JQuery

I'm very grateful for any help given.

I'm posting the code here:

```
<?php


$con = mysql_connect("db-ip","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('errormessage: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$sql2="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername'";
$result=mysql_query($sql2);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if (empty($myusername))
    {
        header('Location:error2.html');
        exit;   
    }

if($count==1)
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO testresult(slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4, time, user) VALUES('$_POST[slider1]', '$_POST[slider2]', '$_POST[slider3]', '$_POST[slider4]', NOW(),'$myusername')";
    }
else    
    {
        header('Location:error.html');
        exit;
    }

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('errormessage:' . mysql_error());
  }

header('Location:done.html');
exit;

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: FYI, you need to read about SQL injection and prepared statements to avoid it **ASAP**. And `stripslashes` is only necessary on horribly misconfigured servers - but it should **never** be used unconditionally.

Comment: ok, thank you for the tips, I will try to avoid that, and read up a bit on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the error is just `undefined`, it can't be caused by PHP. In JavaScript, `undefined` means that the variable which you are trying to use isn't defined.

Another observation was mysql_ functions. You should consider using PDO instead.

From php.net:

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

And this was about functions starting with mysql_.

Comment: @SimonRöstin If the answer was correct, please, accept it as an answer.