# php variable undefined index on isset() submit

Tags: php, forms

Im sorry if this is a stupid question but ive been stuck on this for hours, the closest answer I got was from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436758/php-script-returning-undefined-on-submit) but the issue is not resolved.

Im getting data from checkboxes from a simple form. The forms action takes user to next page, I get the values from checkboxes using

```
$event = $_Post['matchId'];
var_dump($event) confirms values has been received correctly(see image)
```

[image]

The value of $event is an array so im doing the following

```
foreach($event as $key => $eventId)
//some code
```

All is working in the forloop however as soon as I click submit the isset() function gets trigered I get error:

*Undefined Index: matchId*

*Invalid Argument for forloop*

Any idea what I am doing wrong here
Please let me know if you require more info

**update on requested isset code**

```
    $event= $_POST['matchId'];
var_dump($event);
foreach($event as $key => $eventId){
$sql = "Select * FROM events WHERE event_id = $eventId";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$i=0;//counter
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $team1 = $row['team1'];
    $team2 = $row['team2'];
    $id[$i]= $row['event_id']; 

    echo'<h3>'.$team1.' VS '.$team2.'</h3>';
    echo'<select name="id[]">';
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team1'].'">'.$team1.'</option>';
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team2'].'">'.$team2.'</option>';
            echo'</select>';    

            echo'By <select name="score[]">';
            echo'<option value="1">1</option>';
            echo'<option value="2">2</option>';
            echo'<option value="3">3</option>';
            echo'<option value="4">4</option>';
            echo'<option value="5">5</option>';
            echo'<option value="6">6</option>';
            echo'<option value="7">7</option>';
            echo'<option value="8">8</option>';
            echo'<option value="9">9</option>';
            echo'<option value="10">10</option>';
            echo'<option value="11">11</option>';
            echo'<option value="12">12</option>';
            echo'<option value="13">13</option>';
            echo'<option value="14">14</option>';
            echo'<option value="15">15</option>';
            echo'<option value="16">16</option>';
            echo'<option value="17">17</option>';
            echo'<option value="18">18</option>';
            echo'<option value="19">19</option>';
            echo'<option value="20">20</option>';
            echo'</select>';    
        $i++;
}//while
}//for
echo'</legend></fieldset>';
echo'<input type="submit" class="buttono" value="Submit" name="submit" />';
echo'</form>';
echo'</div><!--news-->';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
$x=0;
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $winner){
    $score = $_POST['score'][$key];
    var_dump($score);
    $winnerb = $id[$key];
    echo($winner."-".$winnerb);
    $sql="INSERT INTO picks(member_nr,event_id,pick,score)
            VALUES('$userId','$winnerb','$winner','$score')";
            mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
}//for
}//end isset
```

Comment: sorry typo.....should read id

Comment: You should add more of the codes.

Comment: where is that `isset`?

Comment: @yergo please see updated

Comment: @Marile: where is on updated code the part with `$event`? There are two different code pieces.

Comment: Please include the form aswell

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using two-stage sumitting. On the second request no variables from the first one will be available, they are not related from the server point of view.

Comment: @Epodax please see updated full form code

Comment: There are no checkboxes in your form...

Comment: @jeroen checkboxes are on previous page values are retrieved on this page

Comment: @Cthulhu I am using two-stage submitting please can you ellaborate

Comment: You should make up your mind, switching back and forth between `id` and `matchId` you are just wasting everybody's time.

Comment: @jeroen I was just making the code the same as what I have on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on this part -

```
$event= $_POST['matchId'];
var_dump($event);
foreach($event as $key => $eventId){
$sql = "Select * FROM events WHERE event_id = '$event'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
.....
```

`$_POST['matchId']` is not present. You should add a check for this like -

```
if (!empty($_POST['matchId'])) { //fetch & display data }
else { //display some error or something like this }
```

`$event` event is empty in this case as `$_POST['matchId']` is missing. So it is giving the error regarding `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

If no checkbox is set, `$_POST['id']` will not be set so that will lead to that warning.

Also note that you cannot rely on the `$key` value unless you explicitly set that value of the key in the name attribute of your input element. The image of your `var_dump()` suggests that you are not doing that.

You also have an sql injection problem. You should switch to PDO or mysqli and use a prepared statement with bound variables.